# Cleanly destroy a System V shared memory segment

Tags: c, linux

I am using `shmget`, `shmat` and `shmctl` to respectively get and create a shared memory segment, attach it in processes address space and remove it.

I am wondering if processes can still use the shared memory segment even if it has been detached and asked for removal using

```
shmctl(id, IPC_RMID, ...)
```

in one process.

I am not able to get the information from the man page:

> `IPC_RMID` Mark the segment to be destroyed. The segment will only actually be destroyed after the last process detaches it (i.e., when the `shm_nattch` member of the associated structure `shmid_ds` is zero). The caller must be the owner or creator, or  be privileged. If a segment has been marked for destruction, then the (nonstandard) `SHM_DEST` flag of the `shm_perm.mode`
>   field in the associated data structure retrieved by `IPC_STAT` will be set.

Comment: Even if you can still use it, how would you know the other process(es) will not detach (and therefore destroy) the segment while you're using it?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I don't understand your comment. Does it mean the answer is yes ? Can you explain please ?

Comment: The answer is yes if the process requesting destruction does not detach the segment afterwards, but from your question it seems you already know that. So I assumed you wanted to know if you can still use the address mapped by `shmat()` after both requesting destruction and detaching. Thus, my comment.

Comment: Ok I understand. I edited the question to be more clear.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't understand the paragraph of material quoted from the manual page.  It was written that way, presumably, to answer exactly your question.  The key phrase to pay attention to is: _The segment will only actually be destroyed after the last process detaches it_  So, yes, other processes can still use the shared memory segment until they also detach it.  Note the POSIX definition doesn't have that wording though.  See the NOTES section in the Linux shmctl(2) manual page!

Comment: @GregA.Woods I was having strange behavior and the phrase you quoted just status about destruction. To me, it doesn't clearly indicate that other processes can still use the shared memory segment once it has been marked for deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, it is possible to attach a shared memory segment even if it is already marked to be deleted. However, POSIX.1-2001 does not specify this behavior and many other implementations do not support it.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42479369/2732969 which talks about some of the other OSes (FreeBSD 11+, OpenBSD 5.1+) that implement the "attach to removed segment while it is being kept alive" behaviour.